# How do I find which pywin32 method is bound to a given Microsoft class?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I'm programming with python on Windows 7 using pywin32 for the purpose of manipulating Word and Excel documents. The problem is that the documentation for pywin32 does not clearly tell which method goes under which class. Looking in different Microsoft references like this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb244515(v=office.12).aspx it is not easy to tell which method will work. Trial and error does not work most of the time.
How can i solve this?